# Вывод информации из SQLite

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Есть код, он выводит всю информацию из БД в лист.

```
       final SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dataBase.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query("Messeg",null,null,null,null,null,null);
      if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
         // while (cursor.moveToNext()){
          do {

              UpList.add(0, new DialogSaveData(
                     cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fr")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fr")),
                     cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data"))
             ));

   CastomDialog adapter = new CastomDialog(MainActivity.this, R.layout.castom_dialog_list, UpList);
              //присваиваем адаптер списку
              listChat.setAdapter(adapter);

          }while (cursor.moveToNext());
       }else {
          dataMess.setText("no table");
       }



   }
```

как вывести только те строки где data = "123"?

Comment: пройтись по списку и удалить ненужные строки или применить фильтр

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query("Messeg", 
                                     null, 
                                     "data = ?",
                                     new String[] { "123" },
                                     null, null, null);
```

Comment: А если понадобится несколько параметров? Tо есть, data = "123" and time = "456"

Comment: Тогда третий параметр будет `data = ? and time = ?`, а четвёртый `new String[] { "123", "456" }`.